# Answers vs. comments on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I have noticed that more often than not people tend to respond with answers to questions in comments as opposed to creating answers for a question.  Any thoughts as to why?  I am getting more heavily involved and just want to stay in tune with status quo.

Comment: you can't be downvoted for comments, just flagged.

Comment: Personally, I'll give an answer in the comments section if I can't verify my answer's correctness or if it's basic enough (1-2 sentence answer)

Answer (score 2):

This is speculation of course, but mostly I imagine people answer in comments because the answer was very simple, or the question was against StackOverflow's guidelines. Or it was a duplicate. There is also the known fact that you can't downvote a comment, while answers leave you vulnerable to reputation loss.

In any case, this isn't something you should be too concerned about, StackOverflow's reputation is just a ploy to make people answer questions, just like Reddit has karma, and other websites and their own "game" mechanics.